# custom iphone contact detail screen

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, abaddressbook

I have a requirement to make a screen same as iphone address book contacts detail view. in which we can display contact image, related contact no.s, addresses, urls, etc.

In which i have to show some custom properties in it related to my app.

so I take image control, a couple of labels for and a uitableview to display some contacts.

but the problem is that when i scroll the screen, it only scrolls the uitableview, not the whole screen as we see in iphone.

I am new to iphone development so if somebody give me some code example by which i achieve the functionality would be more helpful for me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a greater area to be scrollable, embed it all within a UIScrollView. There are lots of tutorials for such on net, google for it. There is also some sample code in SDK docs, look at "Scrolling" Apple sample code.

Comment: so how uiscrollview will override the default scroll of uitableview. I have tried it, but since i am new to iphone (monotouch) development. i failed to achieve the functionality. can u plz give some code example

Comment: You are gonna have to be more specific if you are having a problem then.

Comment: Sorry, the "Scrolling" sample code in the SDK is for straight IOS., not monotouch.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a good starting point:

https://github.com/samsoffes/sspersonviewcontroller

its a customisation of the abpersonviewcontroller